# cxf null pointer exception without stack trace

Tags: web-services, nullpointerexception, cxf

am getting a strange error in one of Web Service clients. The error message is:

> WARN org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain -
>   be60c6d00a168d8f2eeadfdd572bf6d2 - Interceptor for
>   {http://service.web.myws.com/}EventLogService#{http://service.web.myws.com/}writeEventRecord
>   has thrown exception, unwinding now java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   null

There is no stack trace for the error. Any suggestions where to start looking for the error cause?

My web service is deployed on a CXF servlet running on Tomcat. I generated a common client for multiple applications using cxf version 2.7.3. But the multiple applications are using version 2.6.2. Is this a problem?

Although I have multiple applications using the same common client, I get the null pointer only on few clients. And they appear to be random also. In my test environments, this error happens every now and then, sometimes I get this error and sometimes it works. But in Production, this hasn't been working for a few days.

UPDATE: We were able to get a stack trace after all:

```
09:51:45.980 [tomcat-http--49] WARN o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - e2b62aba0a168d7d1eef83f92b31397d - Interceptor for {http://service.web.myws.com/}EventLogService#{http://service.web.myws.com/}writeEventRecord has thrown exception, unwinding now
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
                at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor.java:43) ~[cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor.java:29) ~[cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:464) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:367) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:320) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:89) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.writeEventRecord(Unknown Source) [na:na]
                at com.myws.edi.client.EventLogClient.writeEventRecord(EventLogClient.java:71) [ElogServiceClient-2.2-20140729.232322-1.jar:na]
                at com.edi.enrollment.web.service.EnrollmentServiceImpl.processEnrollment(EnrollmentServiceImpl.java:42) [EnrollmentServiceImpl.class:na]
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor505.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
                at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:178) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:64) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_45]
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_45]
                at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:211) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:213) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:154) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:130) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:221) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:141) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647) [servlet-api.jar:na]
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:197) [cxf-bundle-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.35.B]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.35.B]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.35.B]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.35.B]
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:7.0.35.B]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.35.B]
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [catalina.jar:7.0.35.B]
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936) [catalina.jar:7.0.35.B]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.35.B]
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) [catalina.jar:7.0.35.B]
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.35.B]
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.35.B]
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.35.B]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_45]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_45]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
```

Any idea why the Soap header interceptor is throwing a null pointer?

Comment: what is the loggin framework you are using

Comment: slf4j (version 1.0.4) on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a cxf issue - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6030